# How to select parent using on selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic hover that gets activated based on whether a hidden element exists or not. I'm updating my code to incorporate dynamically created elements but have ran into an issue and don't know how to select a parent.

Previously I used `$(".infotip").parent().hover` but have updated to:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".parent-selector", function() {
  $(this).find(".infotip").addClass("active");
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".parent-selector", function() {
  $(this).find(".infotip").removeClass("active");
});
```

So what needs to happen is I need `".parent-selector"` to behave like `$(".infotip").parent()`

Comment: Try to give a class to the parent

Comment: @JoãoPedro That is not an option. As I stated in my answer it's dynamic and may not have control over the parent.

Comment: Could you add an example with your html code to fully understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Does the parent() of .infotip has got any identification tag or class ?
E.g.: data-parent='true', class='parent'
As @andybeli said post the html, or at least a pastebin of it

Comment: @AndreaTulimiero no sorry I thought it was clear that it was dynamic in the sense that it doesnt mater what the parent selector is hence why .parent() was original used. there is no parent selector. What i need to happen is for a workaround to get .on with a selector to behave like .parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the content is dynamic and you mentioned you can't add a class to the parent when it's created, the only way I can think to do this would be to watch for any new elements that have been added and then bind your events.

This function will periodically look for any elements with the `.infotip` class that does not have our custom `events_bound` attribute already. If it finds one, it'll add the attribute and then bind the mouse events to the parent. I've included a fiddle illustrating this with dynamic content.

```
//check for changes in the dom
setInterval(function() {
  $('.infotip:not([events_bound])').each(function() {
    //add attribute so that we don't re-bind to this element
    $(this).attr('events_bound', true);

    //now bind the events to the parent
    $(this).parent().mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).find(".infotip").addClass("active");
    })
    $(this).parent().mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).find(".infotip").removeClass("active");
    })
  });
}, 500);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ybrwv0c8/1/

Of course if there is *anything* identifiable about the parent, then the best way would be to use a selector for your `on`. For instance, if there's a dynamically generated ID with a standard structure like `parent_13835723`, you could do a partial attribute selector like `$('[id^=parent_]')`

You might also be able to use use the jquery `:has` pseudoselector like so. However, this searches *all descendants* for an element, which may not work correctly depending on how your DOM is structured.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ":has('.infotip')", function() {
    $(this).children('.infotip').addClass("active");
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ":has('.infotip')", function() {
    $(this).children('.infotip').removeClass("active");
});
```

However, according to the jquery docs here http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/:

> The expression `$( "div:has(p)" )` matches a `<div>` if a `<p>` exists anywhere 
>   among its descendants, not just as a direct child.
>
> Because :has() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :has() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `$(
>   "your-pure-css-selector" ).has( selector/DOMElement )` instead.

I'm not sure whether the `:has` or `setInterval` method would have better performance.

Comment: Hi Joel, has worked perfectly thank you! I would highlight your answer to show it as being has the one that I went for.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$(".infotip").parent().mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".infotip").addClass("active");
}
```

and

```
$(".infotip").parent().mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".infotip").addClass("active");
}
```

Reference : https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Comment: It has to be able to handle dynamically generated content.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
jQuery(".child").parent().on('mouseenter', function(){
  jQuery(this).css('background', '#f00');
});
jQuery(".child").parent().on('mouseleave', function(){
  jQuery(this).css('background', '#0ff');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/yJXQZo)

**Edit:- Based on further clarification,**

You can attach events to objects when you create them. If you are binding the same events to multiple objects at different times, just create a named function.

OR

A really dirty hack would be to to unbind and rebind the events everytime a hirerchy of elements is added to the DOM.

Something like

```
var init = function() {
   jQuery(".child").parent().off().on('mouseenter', function(){
    jQuery(this).css('background', '#f00');
   });
  jQuery(".child").parent().off().on('mouseleave', function(){
   jQuery(this).css('background', '#0ff');
  });
};
```

Just call the method `init` everytime you add something to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Mohd but as mentioned I need to be able to compensate for dynamically created content. so I must have the selector within on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's custom `:has` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$('document').on('mouseenter', ':has(.infotip)', function () {
  $(this).find(".infotip").addClass("active");
});
$('document').on('mouseleave', ':has(.infotip)', function () {
  $(this).find(".infotip").addClass("active");
});
```

I haven't tested this, as there is no HTML provided in the question, but the documentation seems to indicate it will do what you want.